# Is there any neutral element for the cryptographic hash function SHA256? (or its variants)

Tags: cryptography, exact-string-matching

My question is the following:
Is it possible to compute a string given that after applying a SHA256 function the result is the same string?

Edit for clarification:
If my string A is a neutral element of SHA256, then:
A == SHA256(A) is true.
Does A exists?

Comment: Can you clarify: do you mean two inputs having the same SHA256 output? That would be a SHA256 collision. I didn't think any were yet found for SHA256, but maybe the crypto exchange would have the latest news.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 I think OP is asking for a fixed point of SHA256.

Comment: There is an infinite number of strings and a finite number of SHA256 outputs.

Comment: @greybeard That does not automatically mean there is a fixed point.

Comment: If looking for fixed point computation, see the crypoo exchange. Here is one such thread: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48580/fixed-point-of-the-sha-256-compression-function

Comment: @orlp I think L. Fernandez asks for a *preimage* (another input yielding the same output, not an input that equals its output). Allowable inputs would be pointless for a fixed point; for a limited number of outputs, there would be a limited number of candidates.

Comment: I'm wondering about the motivation of the question. I mean, if you consider function $SHA'(x) = SHA(x) - SHA(0)$, then this function has $0$ as a fixed point while having exactly the same cryptographic properties.

Answer (score 3):

No one knows.  It is believed to be computationally infeasible to find such a string, if one exists.  No one knows whether such a string exists.

By standard heuristics (modelling SHA256 as a random function), there is approximately a $1/e\approx 0.368$ chance that no such input exists, and approximately a $0.632$ chance that such an input exists, so if I were forced to bet, I would bet that it's more likely there exists such an input than that there doesn't, but no one knows.  Don't interpret this chance too seriously: for the specific SHA256 function, either such an input exists or it doesn't.  We don't know which is the case.

If such an input exists, it is believed that it would take about $2^{256}$ steps of computation to find it, which is completely infeasible.

Comment: Can you expand a bit on the heuristic used? If SHA256 is a random function, then it has an infinite domain and a finite codomain, so shouldn't a fixed-point (actually, infinitely many fixed points) exist almost-surely?

Comment: @Steven, no.  It might cycle with period length > 1.  The heuristic is: $\Pr[f(x) \ne x] = 1 - 1/2^{256}$; so $\Pr[\forall x . f(x) \ne x] \approx \prod_x \Pr[f(x) \ne x] = (1 - 1/2^{256})^{2^{256}} \approx 1/e$.

Comment: sorry if I'm missing something stupid. Are you assuming that SHA256 will cycle with a period of at most $2^{256}$?

Comment: @Steven,  I wouldn't say I'm assuming it, but it is true.  If you are iteratively applying SHA256, all that matters is its behavior on $\{0,1\}^{256}$ (after the first iteration, you're only working with 256-bit values, because the output of SHA256 has 256 bits).

Comment: @Steven, $f(x) \in [0 : 2^{256})$. For $x = f(x)$, we must also have $x \in [0 : 2^{256})$, so we don't care about other strings.

Comment: @Dmitry... I'm dumb. I don't know how I missed this... In my head I was thinking of the probability of SHA256 returning one specific string, which is clearly different from a fixed point for the reason you point out. Thanks to you and D.W.